# Getting the Keys and Values from a JSON array in SQL Server 2016

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server-2016

Working in SQL Server 2016 in a procedure and am being passed a JSON object at a nvarchar variable.  The variable looks like this

'{"and":[{"agentId":1},{"status":"In Progress"},{"or":[{"who":{"like":"%Alex%"}},{"status":"Closed"}]}]}'

I need to get it into a table like this

[image: Desired Table Output]

```
SELECT x.[Key], x.[Value] 
FROM OPENJSON(@whereString, '$') AS x;
```

This works until it gets to the embedded array.  I will not know in advance the key names so I think that takes care of JSON_Value and JSON_Query

Comment: The JSON you've given us isn't complete.

Comment: Updated the JSON String for completeness

Answer (score 0):

I was going about it wrong and making it much harder than I needed to.

Using the query:

```
SELECT  x.[key] as keyString, x.[Value] as valueString FROM OPENJSON(@JSONString, '$') AS x
```

will give me the upper level keys and values into a temp table.  Then if the keyvalue for the row is 'and' or 'or'(those keyvalues will have arrays as valueString) I can recursively call the same SQL using just the valueString for that row and it will separate them nicely for me.